# mod_rewrite -- .htaccess redirect to new url with /path and query string intact

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Looking for help in writing an .htaccess file to redirect to a new address with the url/query string intact --

User url input:

```
http://www.example.com/path?query-string=something
```

-or-

```
http://example.com/path?query-string=something
```

will be redirected to:

```
http://subdir.example.com/path?query-string=something
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to worry about the query string.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example.com$
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://subdir.example.com/$1 [R]
```

This will only work with the .htaccess in the root

Comment: You'll need a start-of-string anchor (`^`) to catch the whole URL-path (and not just the last path segment). But in a `.htaccess` context the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ does not start with a slash. You'll also need a _condition_ to check the `Host` header if the subdomain points to the same area on the filesystem, to prevent a redirect loop.

Comment: @MrWhite  Quite correct, I never use .htaccess.  But isn't the ".*" greedy enough to capture the entire URL now?

Comment: "But isn't the ".*" greedy enough to capture the entire URL now?" - yes, now that the slash has been removed.